# not able register my model to wagtail admin using wagtail_hook

Tags: python, django, wagtail

I am trying register my model to wagtail admin but i am not able see my model.

my model is

```
class Abc(models.Model):
    abc_id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    type = models.ForeignKey(AbcTypes, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='type')
    name = models.TextField()
    country = models.ForeignKey(Countries, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='country')
    active = models.BooleanField()
```

i am trying to register my Abc model to wagtail admin using wagtail_hook.

wagtail_hooks.py

```
from wagtail.contrib.modeladmin.options import (
    ModelAdmin, modeladmin_register)
from .models import Abc


class AbcWagtailAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    model = Abc
    menu_label = 'Abc Data'  # ditch this to use verbose_name_plural from model
    menu_icon = 'tag'  # change as required
    menu_order = 200  # will put in 3rd place (000 being 1st, 100 2nd)
    add_to_settings_menu = False  # or True to add your model to the Settings sub-menu
    exclude_from_explorer = False  # or True to exclude pages of this type from Wagtail's explorer view

modeladmin_register(AbcWagtailAdmin)
```

But its not showing to wagtail admin menu.
Help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add 'wagtail.contrib.modeladmin' to your installed apps?

Comment: yes i did and this should not be the answer. It should be comment.

Comment: ok. Sorry about this but I do not have enough reputation to comment at the moment.

Comment: Oh ok no problem.

Answer (score 0):

The file that contains the `AbcWagtailAdmin` definition and the `modeladmin_register` call should be called `wagtail_hooks.py`, not `wagtail_hook.py`

Refs:

- [Wagtail: Hooks](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.11.1/reference/hooks.html)
- [modeladmin docs](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.11.1/reference/contrib/modeladmin/index.html#a-simple-example)

Comment: it's wagtail_hooks.py only.

Comment: Ah, it was a mistake in a question, not in a code. Then, please, make sure that you:

1. Did you include the app that contains this `wagtail_hooks.py` file into `INSTALLED_APPS`? Wagtail loads `wagtail_hooks.py` only for apps that are listed in `INSTALLED_APPS`

2. Your user has permissions to view model admin views.